# Get names and paths from unzip_file()

Tags: filesystem

I Need Some help for unzip_file, this code working fine but i want to add extracted files to wp media library, But i don't know how to get unzip files name and path one by one
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unzip_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i where you i would read the folder where the zip a

```
$path    = '/path/to/extract';
$file    = '/path/to/zip.zip';
unzip_file( $file, $path );
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); // removes empty spots from the array
```

and then do what you want with the files. File names are in the $files array.

```
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    # code...
}
```

Did not test it but i think this should work :)

Comment: It is not what i am looking for, i want to pass unzipped files to a code one by one, and extract files located in current upload directory.

Comment: It is not what i am looking for But its ok, i am happy with your replay.